# What does $E(f)(n)$ and $E^5(n^2)$ mean?

Tags: combinatorics, notation

The following problem is on a worksheet for an applied combinatorics course I am taking:

> Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of positive integers. When $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a function, let $E(f)$ be the function defined by $E(f)(n)=2^{f(n)}$. What is $E^5(n^2)$?

The notation is confusing and unfamiliar to me. From what I understand, $E$ is a function that maps a function to a function. However, I do not know what $E(f)(n)$ and $E^5(n^2)$ mean. My guess is that $E(f)(n)$ is the same as $E(f(n))$, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: I will give you a **blind guess** (best that I can do).  I would guess that (for example) $E^2 \,f(n)$ is equal to **either** $\{E[f(n)]\}^2$ (my first guess) or $E\{ \;E[f(n)] \;\}.$ That is, my 2nd guess interprets $E^2 \cdots$ as $E \circ E \cdots.$

Comment: $E$ is defined on functions, not numbers, so $E(f(n))$ makes no sense. But you are told exactly what $E(f)(n)$ means – it means $2^{f(n)}$.

Comment: But $E^5(n^2)$ seems to me to be an abuse of notation. The only way I can make sense of it is to posit a function $g$ given by $g(n)=n^2$, then apply $E$ five times to $g$; $E(E(E(E(E(g)))))(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

$E(f)$ is a function from $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, $E(f)(n)$ is the *function* $E(f)$ evaluated at $n$. Now, $E$ is *a function that maps functions to functions*, (pause and think for a bit), or more formally we write
$$E:\{f:f\text{ is a function }\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\}\rightarrow \{f:f\text{ is a function }\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\}.$$
So regarding $f(n)=n^2$ as the squaring function, we have
$$E(f)(n)=2^{n^2}.$$
This means that $E(f)$ is the function that maps $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to $2^{n^2}\in\mathbb{N}$. Now repeating,
$$E^2(f)(n)=E(E(f))(n)=2^{(2^{n^2})}.$$
So $E^2(f)$ is the function that maps $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to $2^{(2^{n^2})}\in\mathbb{N}$. Continuing this way, you can calculate $E^5(n^2)$, which is a *function* not a *number*.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, $E$ maps a function to a function. So if $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is some function then $E(f)$ is another function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, let's call it $\widehat{f}$. $E(f)(n)$ is defined as $(E(f))(n)$, that is $\widehat{f}(n)$.

Define $E^k(f)$ inductively:

- $E^0(f) := f$
- $E^{k+1}(f) := E(E^k(f)) = \widehat{E^k(f)}$

The notation $E(f(n))$ makes no sense as the argument of $E$ should be a function while $f(n)$ is a number (in contrast with $f$ which is a function).

As for $E^5(n^2)$, my guess is that this is an abuse of notation. It means ($E^5(f))(n)$ for $$\begin{array}{cccc}f: & \mathbb{N} & \to & \mathbb{N}\\
& n & \mapsto & n^2\end{array}.$$